# How does partialy ionized plasma affect covalent bonds

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electrons, plasma-physics, ions

During partial ionization in plasmas, do diatomic molecules like H2 dissociate into monoatomic states because of the changing states of electron orbitals (exited/ground)?

Comment: Dissociation tends to happen well before ionization in any gas, so far as I know (statistically speaking).  It is possible to ionize molecules, of course, and it is possible for forms of recombination to occur that result in an ionized molecule, I believe.  But the direction you suggest with the phrasing of your question, I would infer that dissociation occurs first then ionization.